# Espresso Instrumented test - How to deny automatically granted permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-espresso

Good day! I have no "GrantPermissionRule.grant" in my test app, but permissions are granted automatically anyway during the test. How to deny this behaviour? I want to test it with UiAutomator.

Comment: That's odd because AFAIK there's no automatic handling of these. Which API are you targeting? Are you sure you've reset the permissions prior to running the test?

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce this behavoir on the local devices. BUT cloud devices (AWS Devices Farm) works ok.

Comment: So only in the cloud are permissions being granted automatically? Many cloud services back this sort of functionality in. If I'm understanding correctly, there should be some configuration you can be doing on the AWS side to disable this. Contact their support? I use CircleCI and have to tell them to not do certain things my local devices or simulators don't do.

Comment: No, vice versa, locally permissions granted automatically even if I removing rule with grant permissions. But no matter already :) Maybe, Mike, you can help me with another question please ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66241159/aws-device-farm-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-androidx ?

Comment: Running into the same issue! Any advice?